# Delphi record helper for double

Tags: delphi

**SITUATION**

I have written a class for second degree equations that looks like this. You can find [here](http://pastebin.com/G0B07yQp) the full code of the class but it's not very relevant for the question.

```
type
 TArrayOfDouble = array of array of double;

type
 TEqSecGrado = class
  private
   //variables
   a, b, c: double;
   delta: double;
   solutions: TArrayOfDouble;
   solRealCount: integer;
   solImaginaryCount: integer;
   class var currentIstances: integer;
   class var totalIstances: integer;
   //methods
   function getDelta(const vala, valb, valc: double): double; overload;
  public
   constructor Create(const a, b, c: double);
   destructor Destroy; override;
   //methods
   function getDelta: double; overload;
   function getSolutions: TArrayOfDouble; virtual;
   //properties
   property valueOfA: double read a;
   property valueOfB: double read b;
   property valueOfC: double read c;
   property realSolutionsCount: integer read solRealCount;
   property imaginarySolutionsCount: integer read solImaginaryCount;
   class property currentEquationsCount: integer read currentIstances;
   class property totalEquationsCount: integer read totalIstances;
 end;
```

I thought to create a new type called `TArrayOfDouble` that will contain the solution of my equation. In the main form I use the class in this way:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var solver: TEqSecGrado;
    soluzioni: TArrayOfDouble;
begin

 //f(x) = 3x^2 - x - 2 -> [sol.1 = 1 | sol.2 = -0,666666666666667]
 solver := TEqSecGrado.Create(3,-1,-2);

 try
  soluzioni := solver.getSolutions; 
  //soluzioni[0][0] = 1; soluzioni[0][1] = 0; 
  //soluzioni[1][0] = -0,666666666666667; soluzioni[1][1] = 0; 
 finally
  solver.Free;
 end;

end;
```

Now I have the results inside `soluzioni` and I can output them. (I have used a matrix because in the first spot I put real solutions, in this case 1 and -0.67, and in the second sport immaginary solutions if needed).

---

**QUESTION**

When I output the solutions I want to convert them into a fraction. I wanted to do something like `soluzioni[a][b].toFraction`. So I thought I could use a record helper for double.

```
type
 TSupport = record helper for Double
   function toFraction: string;
   function toString: string; //I have added this LATER
 end;
```

Here I come with my doubt. Once I have created the `TSupport` and the `toFraction` method, I was able to call soluzioni[0][0].toFraction but I couldn't call soluzioni[i][0].toString.

To solve my problem I decided to add the function toString and everything worked. Does the record helper hide all the other methods? If I removed the record helper instead, I can use again the toString method as always.

I know that helpers are a way to extend a class without using inheritance, but why can I use only the methods I've declared in my helper?

Comment: How can you implement a meaningful function that converts an arbitrary floating point value to a fraction. If you want to do it exactly then you will always get a fraction of the form k/2^n where k and n are integers. Is that what you really want?

Comment: I am doing this for my university math exam and I was suggested to use continued fractions. I am giving only an approximate result. For example sqrt(3)/3 will be converted into a fraction, but of course those 2 values aren't the same and the fraction is just a huge approximation

Comment: Also, your `double` value won't actually be equal to `sqrt(3)/3` because that value is not representable as a binary floating point value

Comment: Sure :) I know that we cannot represent irrational numbers such as that. This is a (very interesting) topic that I am studying and in this class I was trying to find out a reasonable way to get a decent approximation.

Comment: Never mind irrational. You can only represent exactly numbers of the form k/2^m. So you cannot represent 1/3 or 1/10, very simple rational numbers. Out of interest, what course is teaching you maths with programming in Pascal? Must be an applied maths course. Myself I'd have expected to see Python or such like.

Comment: I am a student of applied math and in fact we are using Python and Mathlab. We make calculations of series, integrals, netwon method to approximate roots and so on. My teacher didn't know Delphi and I showed him marco cantu's book I'm studying and he found it interesting too. He asked me to try something to bring as "extra". I have made a project for my exam and it's entirely python oop, Delphi is just something in 2nd plan

Comment: That sounds great. Enjoy! I miss days as a student of maths......

Comment: Thanks! I really love maths and OOP languages (in particular python/java/delphi), and I guess I can understand your feeling ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A limitation of class and record helpers is that only one can be active at once. The `ToString` method of `Double` is actually implemented in a record helper provided by the Delphi RTL. Once you attach your helper to the type, then the RTL helper is no longer active.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)#Helper_Syntax) says:

> You can define and associate multiple helpers with a single type. However, only zero or one helper applies in any specific location in source code. The helper defined in the nearest scope will apply. Class or record helper scope is determined in the normal Delphi fashion (for example, right to left in the unit's uses clause).

This is a long standing issue which Embarcadero has known about ever since helpers were introduced. In many long years they have not addressed the issue and with the best will in the world I think you should assume that they never will.

So, you have two choices:

1. Attach your own helper, and accept that the functionality of the RTL helper will not be available to you.
2. Implement your functionality by means other than a helper.

Comment: Ok, so that happened because the compiler is ignoring the RTL helper and it cares only of the last implemented helper (in this case, mine)

Comment: Correct. I've added a doc link, and the relevant excerpt

Comment: Just as an FYI: You can have multiple CLASS helpers active at the same time. CLASS helpers support inheritance, so you can actually define YOUR class helper as an extension of the previous one, as in _TStringsHelper = CLASS HELPER(VclHelpers.TStringsHelper) FOR TStrings_ and both the VclHelpers.TStringsHelper and your just declared TStringsHelper from the current UNIT will be accessible. Unfortunately, RECORD helpers doesn't support inheritance, so the only way I have found to "extend" an existing RECORD helper is to re-implement the helper as an INLINE method that calls the old one.

Comment: @Heartware: If you read your own explanation you will see that there is still only ONE helper "active" even with class helpers, it just happens that you can use inheritance to inherit capabilities of some other helper into that ONE active helper.  Assuming of course that what you need can be achieved with single-inheritance.  If there are two helpers (unrelated by inheritance) and you wish to introduce another, then you have to choose which one to inherit from because you cannot inherit from both and ONLY ONE can be active.

Comment: @Deltics: I guess that depends on your understanding on "Active". The methods in both CLASS helpers are directly accessible, and thus - in my understanding - "Active".

Comment: It's usually at this point where an Embarcadero employee chips in to tell us that they have a patent on helpers as of that somehow makes us poor users feel better.

Comment: @Heartware - no, an "understanding" that when class A inherits from class B then if class A is in scope then class B is also in scope is what is called a **MIS**understanding.  Inheritance and scope are two separate things.  The "active" helper for a type is *the one and only one helper in scope* for that type.  For a class helper, this will include any inherited characteristics of some other helper that is NOT in scope.  But that does not alter which *one* is in scope.